# SignalR client not receiving server messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-signalr

My SignalR client doesn't receive any messages from the server. What am I missing here?

**Server Hub**

```
namespace DoneITWebAPI.Hubs
{
    public interface ITypedHubClient
    {
        Task BroadcastMessage(string name, string message);
    }

    public class ServiceStatusHub : Hub<ITypedHubClient>
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.BroadcastMessage(name, message);
        }

    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    IHubContext<ServiceStatusHub, ITypedHubClient> _chatHubContext;
    public DemoController(IHubContext<ServiceStatusHub, ITypedHubClient> chatHubContext)
    {
        _chatHubContext = chatHubContext;
    }

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        _chatHubContext.Clients.All.BroadcastMessage("ReceiveMessage", "test");
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

**Console Client App**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl("http://localhost:64165/ServiceStatusHub")
        .Build();

        connection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
        {
            GetMessage(user, message);
        });

        connection.StartAsync();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    public static void GetMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        //Not hitting here
    }
}
```

Comment: did u check the connection is getting established ?

Comment: can you also show us, how do you register your hubs in your `Startup.cs` and how do you actually send that message that you want to receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My SignalR client doesn't receive any messages from the server. What am I missing here?

Based on your code, we can find that you use [strongly typed hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-5.0#strongly-typed-hubs), and you define and name client method as `ReceiveMessage` on console app.

To make you can call that client method as expected , you can try to modify your hub code as below.

```
public interface ITypedHubClient
{
    Task ReceiveMessage(string name, string message);
}

public class ServiceStatusHub : Hub<ITypedHubClient>
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.ReceiveMessage(name, message);
    }

}
```

*And change the code in API action*

```
_chatHubContext.Clients.All.ReceiveMessage("system", "test");
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but what exactly did you change in your example except renaming Broadcast to Receive? that shouldn't make a difference

Comment: I am unable to send typed messages from an API to clients. Are typed hubs for client-sent messages only?